# how to do rdd transformations with streaming dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

i want to do custom transform with stream dataframe like:

```
lines = spark \
    .readStream....blabla

df1 = line.rdd.map(xxx).flatMap(xxx)
```

but i got error:

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;\nbigpipe'

someone help?

Comment: It is not possible. What do you want to do? Streaming's aim is to make things more high-level and leave RDD API for Dataset/DataFrame API. Describe your case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example from the documentation

```
# Create DataFrame representing the stream of input lines from connection to localhost:9999
lines = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("socket") \
    .option("host", "localhost") \
    .option("port", 9999) \
    .load()

# Split the lines into words
words = lines.select(
   explode(
       split(lines.value, " ")
   ).alias("word")
)

# Generate running word count
wordCounts = words.groupBy("word").count()

# Start running the query that prints the running counts to the console
query = wordCounts \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("complete") \
    .format("console") \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

The details of which can be found here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html

Comment: This is a dataframe implementation whereas the question is about RDD

Comment: With Spark structured streaming all operations are now done with a Dataset API abstraction. There is no RDD level abstraction that is provided.

Comment: @JayadeepJayaraman the dataset API in Scala supports map/flatMap so is it supported in Python? Instead of `.rdd.map(..)` is there another way to call `map` in Python?